# Split String and Number in Pandas Column

Tags: python, pandas

I am a beginner in python. I have a `dataframe` looks like this:

```
df
No  ID
1   52Device-24-03HAntang
2   40Device-16HAntang
```

I want to split the `ID` column. My expected result looks like this:

```
Result
No  ID                      No_ID   Device        Code  Name
1   52Device-24-03HAntang   52      Device-24-03  H     Antang
2   40Device-16HAntang      40      Device-16     H     Antang
```

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If need split by uppercase letters first add space before uppercase by [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) and then split by this space with [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
cols = ['No_ID','Device','Code','Name']
df[cols] = df['ID'].str.replace(r"([A-Z])", r" \1").str.split(expand=True)
print (df)
   No                     ID No_ID        Device Code    Name
0   1  52Device-24-03HAntang    52  Device-24-03    H  Antang
1   2     40Device-16HAntang    40     Device-16    H  Antang
```